# Cannot have a has_one :through association ' where the :through association is a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following associations. PropertyOwner is a join model which belongs to a property and polymorphically belongs to an owner, which in the below example is a ForeclosureDefense. Everything works well, until I had the has_one :main_property. The idea is the ForeclosureDefense model can have many properties, but the last property is the main property:

```
class ForeclosureDefense < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :property_owners, as: :owner
  has_many :properties, through: :property_owners
  has_one :main_property, through: :property_owners, source: :property, order: 'created_at desc'
end

class PropertyOwner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: :true
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :property_owners
  has_many :owners, through: :property_owners
  has_many :foreclosure_owners, through: :property_owners, source: :owner, source_type: "ForeclosureDefense"
  has_many :folder_owners, through: :property_owners, source: :owner, source_type: "Folder"
end
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use that has_one :main_property association, I get the following error:

ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection: Cannot have a has_one :through association 'ForeclosureDefense#main_property' where the :through association 'ForeclosureDefense#property_owners' is a collection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [has\_one through association with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366460/has-one-through-association-with-condition)

Comment: Flagging this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366460/has-one-through-association-with-condition

I know this one came first but the linked question has more votes and a better answer

Answer (score -3):

My solution was just to add it as a class-level macro:

```
def main_property
  properties.order('created_at desc').first
end
```