# has_one through association with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have 3 relevant tables/models. I would like to *retrieve the user which has organized a party*, given a Party record, a join table with a boolean `organized` column, and a users table.

My best attempt so far (this one makes the most sense to me after *much* fiddling). I've omitted the irrelevant columns.

```
class Party
  # party_id

  has_many   :parties_users
  has_many   :users, through: :parties_users, source: :user
  has_one    :organizer,
             -> { where organizer: true },
             through: :parties_users,
             source: :user
```

---

```
class PartiesUser
  # party_id
  # user_id
  # organized:bool

  belongs_to :party
  belongs_to :user
```

---

```
class User
  # user_id
  has_many : parties_users
```

---

The above setup raises the following error, which I honestly don't fully understand:
`ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection (Cannot have a has_one :through association 'Party#organizer' where the :through association 'Party#parties_users' is a collection. Specify a has_one or belongs_to association in the :through option instead.)`

I know I can do this via an instance method, but given the frequency types of use, my app would massively benefit from having this as an association.

Comment: I feel like the `parties_users` should not contain the data related to who organized the party, but the party itself should have `belongs_to :organizer, class_name: 'User'` (or a separate `organizers` if you want many-to-many)

Comment: This is, in fact, the implementation that I have currently, but it's also resulted in a bunch of messy queries where I have to manually merge users from the join table, and the organizer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't have a has_one through a has_many.

You could (instead) do it this way if the organizer flag is on the join record...

```
has_many :parties_users
has_many :users, through: :parties_users, source: :user
has_one :main_party_user, -> {where organizer: true}, class_name: 'PartiesUser'
has_one :organizer, through: :main_party_user, class_name: 'User'
```

Comment: This works! However, `source: :enthusiast` must be provided on the last line

Comment: I think it should be `source: :user` instead of `class_name: 'User'`